# Decision making query - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to make decision if the transaction is success or failed using SQL query.
I have two tables, where unit, values and dates are stored for different account.
Here is my condition:

```
if(unit != 0 and value == 0)
{
 failed
}
if(unit == 0 and value != 0)
{
 failed
}
if(date == NULL)
{
  failed
}
```

I have to update this success and failure in another table.

This is how I'm trying to implement above logic using SQL:

```
 select F.ACCOUNT_ID,F.FUND_ID,
 CASE UNIT
 WHEN 0 THEN 'FAILED',
 CASE VALUE
 WHEN 0 THEN 'FAILED'
 END
 ACCOUNT A right join FUND F
 ON A.ACCOUNT_ID = F.ACCOUNT_ID
```

Hope I have explained it correctly. How can I write a T-SQL query for this?

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as using your initial C#-looking code:

```
CASE
  WHEN Unit <> 0 AND value = 0 THEN 'Failed'
  WHEN Unit = 0 AND value <> 0 THEN 'Failed'
  WHEN date IS NULL THEN 'Failed'
  ELSE 'Success'
END
```

You could also achieve the same results with a massive () OR () OR () structure, but this will be easier to maintain.